# Fine-tuning Resnet using pre-convoluted features

Tags: pytorch, resnet, vgg-net

As we know that convolution layers are expensive to calculate , I would like to compute the output of the convolution layers once and use them to train the fully connected layer of my Resnet, in order to speed up the process.

In the case of a VGG model, we can compute the output of the first convolutional part as follows

```
x = model_vgg.features(inputs)
```

But how can I do to extract features from a Resnet?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Assuming you're talking about the `torchvision.models`'s ResNet, then you can't extract features out-of-the-box. You'd have to implement the method (open-source projects are amazing :)) or extend the class to one that implements it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can try hacking through the net. I'll use resnet18 as an example:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torchvision.models import resnet18

net = resnet18(pretrained=False)
print(net)
```

You'll see something like:

```
....
      (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )
  )
  (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(1, 1))
  (fc): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1000, bias=True)
```

Let's store the Linear layer somewhere, and in its place, put a dummy layer. Then the output of the whole net is actually the output of the conv layers.

```
x = torch.randn(4,3,32,32) # dummy input of batch size 4 and 32x32 rgb images
out = net(x)
print(out.shape)
>>> 4, 1000 # batch size 4, 1000 default class predictions

store_fc = net.fc      # Save the actual Linear layer for later
net.fc = nn.Identity() # Add a layer which actually does nothing
out = net(x)
print(out.shape)
>>> 4, 512 # batch size 4, 512 features that are the input to the actual fc layer.
```

Comment: Thank you so much! What I did instead is just remove the fc layer

`conv_layers = list(model_resnet.children())[:-1]`
 `model = nn.Sequential(*conv_layers)`
  `for param in model.parameters():`
      `param.requires_grad = False`

Comment: Ooh, that's nice too. But if you put them all in Sequential, does the residual block/skip connection thingy of resnet still happen? I thought that mechanism is implemented in the forward() method.